# Angular material matstepper to unselect all the steps

Tags: angular, angular-material

In Mat-stepper at initial rendering i don't want first step to be selected. I want all the steps to be unselected (unfilled) steps.

Answer (score 2):

I checked the angular documentation and couldn't find anything related how to achieve this. 
The only thing that popped up into my mind is that you can modify to select/unselect steps is the index of the current step. 
The solution that I propose is to set the selected index property of the MatStepper ViewChild to -1.

```
  @ViewChild('stepper') stepper: MatStepper;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.stepper.selectedIndex = -1;
  }
```

It works because in the implementation of the mat-stepper,
all of the steps are foreached and based on the selcectedIndex matching the index of the steps array and as we know it starts from 0:

```
"selectedIndex === i"
```

[Reference](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/stepper/stepper-vertical.html)

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-stepper-program-n7beys

**Update:**
The top approach doesn't quite make it.
When you click on a step it throws an error because you are accessing the step array with index of -1. Browsing thought the source code I can offer another approach of extending either mat vertical or horizontal stepper and providing different functionality for when you step and provide -1.

You can also create your own custom implementation and base it on cdkStepper -> https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-stepper-using-the-cdk-stepper

And if you dont manage to do that you can check the stepper from teradata. I know that they provide an extended api.
 https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/components/steps/overview

Comment: But on click of any one step it is throwing error in console                                                                                            ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'interacted' of undefined
    at MatHorizontalStepper.push../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/stepper.es5.js.CdkStepper._anyControlsInvalidOrPending (stepper.es5.js:705)
    at MatHorizontalStepper.set [as selectedIndex] (stepper.es5.js:363)
    at AppComponent.push../src/app/app.component.ts.AppComponent.ngAfterViewInit (app.component.ts:21)
    at callProviderLifecycles (core.js:22416)

Comment: Let me see what is going on

Answer (score 1):

Late response but This works in Angular Material 12.0 version.

```
@ViewChild('stepper') stepper: MatStepper;

 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.stepper.['_updateSelectedItemIndex'](-1);
  }
```

Inspired by answer from [@ppavlov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5683901/ppavlov)

Answer (score 1):

```js
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.stepper.['_updateSelectedItemIndex'](-1);
  }
```

the correct code that works for me is :

```js
this.stepper['_updateSelectedItemIndex'](-1);
```

this.stepper'_updateSelectedItemIndex';